# Adding background color changes width of bootstrap grid element?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I just started with bootstrap and I'm about to build a grid for my layout.

I want to add background colors to my grid elements, so I tried to add custom classes like .logo { background-color: #202020; } to the corresponding div. But adding the class - only with color attribute! - changes the width of the div (see screenshot)? I can't explain this.
I already searched for this problem, but adding a custom class seems to be best practice for adding background colors etc.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMbQ3.jpg)

So here is the code -

HTML

```
<div class="container main-container">

    <div class="row">

        <!-- navigation -->
        <div class="col-md-2 nav">

            <!-- logo -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 logo">
                    <h1>Logo</h1>
                    <h2>Dashboard</h2>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- user info -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 user">
                    profile pic
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 user">
                    more lorem ipsum
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>


        <!-- content -->
        <div class="col-md-10">

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    Some lorem ipsum
                </div>

            </div>


        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

& adding bootstrap.min.css in the head

CSS

```
body {
    background-size: cover;
}

.main-container {
    margin-top: 5%;
    background-color: #f6f5f1;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

/* sidebar styling */
.nav {
    background-color: #2b2b2b;
    color: #fff;
}

.logo {
    background-color: #202020;
}

.user {

}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e1vx1mhb/

Well - I already found a "workaround". I added background colors to the following rows, too, and they become wider as well. But I don't think this is the best solution.

So any thoughts? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the updated [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gschambial/e1vx1mhb/4/)

Adding `clearfix` class instead of row for inner DIVs will solve your problem and comment `background-size: cover;` css property.

Answer (score 2):

It happens because of the padding. If you don't use `box-sizing:border-box;` and add background to that bootstrap column, the background applies to the padding as well. I've added this global rule to your jsfiddle:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

and it all works how you intended. Read up on box-sizing, I always use border-box when I build my sites, this way there is no surprises when it comes to sizes of the elements when I add padding or border.

https://jsfiddle.net/e1vx1mhb/1/